# InApp Purchases returned invalid Xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin.ios, in-app-purchase

**I am trying to implement inapp purchases in Xamarin.iOS. Its showing different behaviors for two different accounts. For one account inApp Products are shown valid and invalid for another developer account. I have checked the certificates and, product IDs and bundle IDs. Everything seems o be fine.**

```
 public InAppPurchaseManager PurchaseManager = new InAppPurchaseManager();
        void Initialization()
        {
            PurchaseManager.PurgeProducts();
            if (PurchaseManager.CanMakePayments)
            {

            }
            else
            {

                using (var alert = new UIAlertView("Error!", "Sorry but you cannot make purchases from the In App Billing store. Please try again later.", null, "OK", null))
                {
                    alert.Show();
                }
            }
            PurchaseManager.QueryInventory(new string[] { productID });
            PurchaseManager.ReceivedValidProducts += PurchaseManager_ReceivedValidProducts;
            PurchaseManager.ReceivedInvalidProducts += PurchaseManager_ReceivedInvalidProducts;
            PurchaseManager.InAppProductPurchased += PurchaseManager_InAppProductPurchased;
        }

        private void PurchaseManager_ReceivedInvalidProducts(string[] productIDs)
        {

        }

        private void PurchaseManager_ReceivedValidProducts(List<InAppProduct> products)
        {
            _
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the account. I did not set the account settings for inapp purchases like providing tax information and other things. To enable inapp purchases from an account admin must sumbit the required legal documents to enable inapp purchases :)

thnx